# Doctrine - MongoDB, id from type BinData

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, symfony-2.3, doctrine-odm

I have MongoDB data which uses `_id` as `BinData` object.

```
{  
   "_id" : BinData(3,"ABRWTIFGPEeSFf69fISAOA=="),
   "Email" : "XXXXX@msn.com", 
}
```

How to set annotation mapping for `_id` from type `BinData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after [#444](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/444) merged into master ,we can deal with `BinData Obejct` into `MongoDB` as `MongoBinData Object` with same type `\MongoBinData::UUID` (3)

Annotation we must use int this case when we use Doctrine MongoDB ODM is `@Id(type="bin_uuid")`

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's BinData is backed by the PHP Class MongoBinData.

The Doctrine documentation at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#bin says that you can use the `@Bin` annotation, or other annotations starting with `@Bin`.

Following http://bsonspec.org/#/specification, the binary subtype "3" is "UUID (Old)" which is deprecated in favour of type `4` (UUID). I think you should be able to use `@BinUUID` for this type for which http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#binuuid has the documentation.

Comment: when i use [ @MongoDB\BinUUID ] throw Exception: No identifier/primary key specified for Document